# Creating a new column of categorical variables based on date range

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe, `dat`, with the following columns:

```
   record_id date       
       <dbl> <date>     
 1    111111 1956-10-28 
 2    222222 1956-10-28 
 3    333333 1956-10-29 
 4    444444 1956-10-29 
 5    555555 1956-10-30
```

In which I want to create a new column which takes on different values based on whether the date is between a specific range. The desired output is this:

```
  record_id date       new_var 
       <dbl> <date>     <chr> 
 1    111111 1956-10-28 test1
 2    222222 1956-10-28 test1
 3    333333 1956-10-29 test1
 4    444444 1956-10-29 test1
 5    555555 1956-10-30 test1
```

My first attempt was the following:

```
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate
    new_var = ifelse(date > as.Date("1954-03-12") & date < as.Date("1958-12-08"), "test1"),
    new_var = ifelse(date > as.Date("1958-09-13") & date < as.Date("1964-03-08"), "test2")
  )
```

Which doesn't give me what I want (please don't laugh!). Would anyone be able to help me as to how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few syntax issues in your `ifelse` statement.

Since you are using `dplyr` you can simplify this with `case_when` and `between` functions .

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(new_var = case_when(
           between(date, as.Date("1954-03-13"), as.Date("1958-12-07"))~"test1",
           between(date, as.Date("1958-09-14"), as.Date("1964-03-07"))~ "test2")
         )

#  record_id       date new_var
#1    111111 1956-10-28   test1
#2    222222 1956-10-28   test1
#3    333333 1956-10-29   test1
#4    444444 1956-10-29   test1
#5    555555 1956-10-30   test1
```